# Eclipse CDT variable colors in editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I hope this is an OK question to ask here. It's programming related so I thought it would be better here than superuser. So I'm using the CDT C++ eclipse plugin. I know how to change the colors the editor uses for certain things. But is there a way to make it so all variables are DIFFERENT colors? For example in KDevelop, it sets local variables and class variables different colors and bolds class variables. Can I replicate that in CDT?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Eclipse text editor offers some level of color customizations for syntax.

You can check it on: **Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Syntax Coloring**

There are several elements that can be changed, including Code, Assembly, Comments, Preprocessor and Doxygen.

Under Code, its possible to change the color of certain variable types, like global variables, local variable declarations, local variable references, and parameter variables.

But I don't think its able to change the color of every single variable you declared in the code. Maybe you can search for an Eclipse plugin to do that.